# Select lines that contain anything different from 0.00

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have multiple lines in a notepad++ document and I want to find all the lines that contain something other than "0.00"
Ie

```
Timetaken: 2.39
Timetaken: 1.30
Timetaken: 0.75
Timetaken: 0.00
Timetaken: 0.43
```

and I want to find all those that don't have a value of 0.00?

Is that possible with notepad++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current accepted answer is wrong; it will not match the following even though it should:

```
Timetaken: 0.0
Timetaken: 0.01
Timetaken: 0.0asdf
foo Timetaken: 0.0 bar
Timetaken: 10.0
```

There are four things wrong with it:

1. It needs anchors (`^` and `$`) so that it only matches the Timetaken thing if it is the only thing the line consists of.
2. `[00]` is equivalent to just `0`, since it's a character class.
3. `.` is not escaped.
4. There is an unnecessary `.*`.

So, the fixed regex:

```
^Timetaken: (?!0\.00)$
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Notepad++ (because I only use Linux for development work) but I've tried your sample lines in the text editor Kate and found the following regular expression works to select only lines which fit the pattern above but do not contain "0.00" as their numeric value:

```
^Timetaken: (?!0\.0+$)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$
```

This regex says:

- "Timetaken: " appears immediately after the start of the line.
- The value "0." followed by one or more zeroes until the end of the line is **not** found. (This is known as a negative lookahead assertion.)
- One or more digits is found, followed by a dot, followed by one or more digits, up to the end of the line.
- If the numeric value is not zero then it is captured in group one by the regex matcher.

Looking at [the documentation for using regex in Notepad++](http://npp-wiki.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions) I suspect that this pattern will work fine in that text editor too.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got other content in the file besides the lines you've shared here you could use this regex instead:

^(.(?!0\.00))*$

I.E. if you have lines that don't begin with Timetaken:

Answer (score -1):

Press **Ctrl+f** to search and use the below regular expression

```
Timetaken: (?!.*[0].[00])
```

It will find all the lines other than "Timetaken: 0.00" and the output is as follows

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Once again you have answered my question amazingly! @vembutech

Comment: `[00]` is a character class so it won't match `00`; just `0`